How do Linux drivers communicate with my Qt app
I'm creating an embedded Linux app with Qt Quick. Basically, I have some sensors that I need to output in the UI. I'm trying to wrap my head around all this process, but I still have some gray areas.
As far as I understand, a temperature sensor will be controlled by the I2C driver in my embedded Linux app. This driver is something that I need to add in my layers when using Yocto. So far I feel I understand this part.
On the other side, I've a UI created in QT which has a main.cpp file. If I understand correctly, this is my main entry point to my entire application? From this main.cpp I can create a simple call to the I2C driver and read the sensor data?
I can't even write the correct question because I can't wrap my head around all these binaries and the code flow.
I already have a Qt quick app working and a placeholder code to simulate the sensor values and update the UI.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The user interface to Linux drivers can be found under /dev in the file system. Look for devices like i2c-0, i2c-1, ...
These devices need to be opened by the application, for example like this:
int file = open("/dev/i2c-0", O_RDWR); // Name your correct device!

If this works, you can try to communicate with your device:
int addr = 0x40; /* Insert correct I2C address */

if (ioctl(file, I2C_SLAVE, addr) < 0) {
  /* Check errno for errors */
  exit(1);
}

Now you can read() or write() to your I2C device:
char buf[3] = { /* Whatever */ };

if (write(file, buf, 3) != 3) {
  /* ERROR HANDLING: I2C transaction failed */
}

Note: there is no difference to calling a UART device or any other Linux driver, so you can take any code you find using Linux drivers.
Now wrap all this up into a module and hook it up to the Qt Quick C++ API.

Please don't refer to /dev as "the device tree", as that seriously conflates userspace {character, block} device nodes with Open Firmware Device Tree.

Now that you mention it: this question or any answer should indeed be split up into several items: setting up the device tree in Yocto, implementing a C++ backend for QML and wrapping it all up with the Qt Quick API. I was assuming the backend is the problem, but there might be more to it.
